# Django admin interface custom logo not found 404

Tags: python, django, interface, admin

I have just started with django
I created a new project and installed Django admin-interface also installed the bootstrap theme then tried to upload my logo in the theme settings but the logo doesn't appear , also I get this error in the terminal "GET /admin-interface/logo/logo.png HTTP/1.1" 404 2164

I haven't changed anything in the default code

Comment: did you add **admin_interface** and **colorfield**  to **settings.INSTALLED_APPS** before **django.contrib.admin**

Comment: Did you use `py manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: yes I did use collectstatic

Comment: I did add  admin_interface and colorfield to settings.INSTALLED_APPS